# How to get Queue using context.lookup() in oracle 11g

Tags: java, queue, jms, weblogic11g, initial-context

I want to create Queue and the MessageDrivenBean in Oracle 11g.
I created the JMS Module on Weblogic and into it I created Queue and ConnectionFactory.
JDBC names looks like:
Queue: jms/EvZahQueue
ConnectionFactory: jms/ConnectionFactory

I tried to get them with:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/QueueConnector");
queue = (Queue) context.lookup("jms/EvZahQueue");
```

But, I've got an exception like this:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/jms/QueueConnector in /app/webapp/registri-view/31900933.; remaining name 'comp/env/jms/QueueConnector'
```

Also, I tried with:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/QueueConnector");
queue = (Queue) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/EvZahQueue");
```

And I tried to create default properties and to put them into `new InitialContext()` but nothing changed.

What should I do? Maybe I need to write something in `web.xml`, `ejb-jar.xml`, `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`?

Comment: is it, maybe Oracle WebLogic 11g?

Comment: Yes it is Oracle WebLogic 11g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem.
In Weblogic, I must create subdeployment of my JMS module (Oracle said it is not mandatory, but in my case it seems it is) and then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> From the WebLogic console, **Environment** -> **Servers** -> **View
>   JNDI Tree**.

[image]

> From there, find the queue, **take note of the nested path** where it's
>   located, then use that path in the lookup.

[image]

Comment: Hi Raffian. First of all, thank you for helping me. 
I can find QueueConnectionFactory you showed in this example, but I can't find the Queue I created, named EvZahQueue. I am not sure what I need to do.